# How to target two media queries using SASS interpolation?

Tags: sass

I have the following SASS variables:

```
$mobile: "only screen and (max-width : 767px)";
$tablet: "only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px)";
$desktop: "only screen and (min-width : 1025px)";
```

I can do this without any problems:

```
@media #{$mobile} {

   /* my styles for mobile displays */

}
```

But how can I target *two* media queries at the same time?

This gives me a syntax error:

```
@media #{$mobile + "and" + $tablet} {

    /* my styles for mobile and tablet displays */

}
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't give you CSS error but is slightly different from what you need:

```
@media #{$mobile}, #{$tablet} {
   /* my styles for mobile and tablet displays */
}
```

From MDN docs:

> Comma-separated lists behave like the logical operator or when used in
>   media queries. When using a comma-separated list of media queries, if
>   any of the media queries returns true, the styles or style sheets get
>   applied. Each media query in a comma-separated list is treated as an
>   individual query, and any operator applied to one media query does not
>   affect the others. This means the comma-separated media queries can
>   target different media features, types, and states.

The thing is that concat that you are making with string interpolation isn't 
compiled to valid CSS. Read more about media query logic [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: In the future, please avoid answering duplicate questions.  Interpolation is a Sass specific construct (note the tag says "sass").

Comment: I think it's great that @Drops answered this question because it's completely different from the "duplicate question" you posted above. Thanks again.

Comment: @cimmanon Main reason why I answered this question is rep that Tintin have, maybe dude needs answer asap and isn't capable to deduce solution from your duplicate example. I don't mind if this whole question gets deleted (if possible) afterwards. But mos def will keep that in mind for future answers. Cheers

Comment: @Drops you answer above work as an or statement (mobile or tablet).

Comment: @cinnamon: I don't see your point here. If other people's "inabilities" bother you so much, why do you even spend time on this board? Don't hesitate to delete my `duplicate question` by the way.

Answer (score 2):

THe answer above works as an `or` statement http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

if you want to use them as an `and` is the following.

```
$mobile: "(max-width : 767px)";
$tablet: "(min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px)";
$desktop: "(min-width : 1025px)";

@media only screen and #{$mobile} and #{$tablet} {
   /* my styles for mobile and tablet displays */
}
```

OUTPUT

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* my styles for mobile and tablet displays */
}
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/3784cbe7eca84039ec75

Comment: `...but that is effectively and or.` Chris, CSS Tricks :D