# SCSS media query with interpolation

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I am not able to use media query heading as a interpolation. While using it like the following it gives an error

```
$token-screen-md: "@media only screen and (min-width: 48rem)";
#{$token-screen-md} {
  display: table-row;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Could someone please help me to resolve this?

"Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected selector.
@media only screen and (min-width: 48rem){"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mobile: "only screen and (max-width : 767px)"; 
$tablet: "only screen and (min-width : 768px)";
$desktop: "only screen and (min-width : 1025px)";

@media #{$mobile} {
  /* my styles for mobile displays */
}`
```

Taken from [How to target two media queries using SASS interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290316/how-to-target-two-media-queries-using-sass-interpolation)